# How to get a loop in python to skip one iteration in the loop when it encounters a cell with a particular input? See below.

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a program that pretty much consists of a simple loop that goes through a bunch of numbers that are arranged in a column (among many other columns in the spreadsheet) and it consists of a bunch of if-statements that check if each number is within a particular range and based on which range it falls into, it will perform a specific task.

However, the problem is that, every now and then, some of the cells in the column will just contain a "-" symbol and won't have any numbers and the program just stops there, since it can't compare the dash sign to the ranges of numbers I'm making my if-statement comparisons to. What's the best way to just skip over these types of cells? I can't delete those cells because I've got like 100,000+ rows and there are other columns in the spreadsheet that are of use to me. I tried using the break and continue function but for some reason the program just doesn't read it as such.

```
 for x in range(1,1000):
    if value[x] == "-":
      break # I tried this with the continue function as well
```

Comment: `continue` should work. If it doesn't, we'll need to see more of your code to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these will work:

```
for x in range(1,1000):
    if value[x] == "-":
        pass
    else:
        # do work
```

or

```
for x in range(1, 1000):
    if value[x] == "-":
        continue
    # do work
```

Note that the indentation is crucial to make the right things happen at the right time.

`break` in Python is like `exit for` and `exit while` from other languages; it ends the loop, rather than skipping one item.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(1, 1000):
    if value[x] == '-': continue
    doImportantThings ()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(1,1000):
    if value[x] == "-":
        continue
```

I prefer it to *else* because you avoid extra indent - each indent makes code fragment less readable, the longer the fragment - the worth

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a problem of not getting complete match in your comparison.

ie. if the string in `value[x] = "- "` then `value[x] == "-"` will be false.

try this:

```
for x in range(1,1000):
    # this will be true if there is a '-' in the string at all
    if "-" in value[x]: 
      continue
```

Note that this approach might give false positives in the event that you have valid cells that just happen to contain a `-`.